# Rails custom generator to generate model & destroy model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, generator

I can create a model very easily in a generator

```
class JoinerGenerator <  Rails::Generators::Base
   .....
   generate("model", "#{new_model_name}")
   .....
end
```

So I would run

```
 rails g joiner newmodel
```

How do I destroy it?

e.g.

```
  rails d joiner newmodel
```

As this generator only "generates" and doesnt destroy, I assumed it was automatically done

Comment: You can destroy model by calling `rails d model newmodel`.

Comment: Not what I want to DO, I am using a lib/generator to build somethings, I want to remove the whole lot with the opposite command, i,e, a user uses my generator and then wants to rollback so to they write "rails d joiner newmodel" - how would my generator know what action was being called? Destroy or Generate

Comment: Looks like you need something like this. http://factore.ca/on-the-floor/126-reversible-rails-generators